# Swipe working in Browser but not in Android - Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, mobile-application

I am trying to make Swipe in cordova for mobile app and it is working in Browser but not in Android.

Below swipe left and swipe right functionality is working on browser but not on android. Can anyone help me out ?

**HTML:**

```
<div id ="div1" class="app1">
    <Button id="b1" class="option option1" >NEWS</Button>
    <Button id="b2" class="option option2" >EMERGENCY</Button>
    <Button id="b3" class="option option3" >CONTACT</Button>
    <Button id="b4" class="option option4" >MUSIC</Button>
</div>

<div id ="div2" class="app2 hide">
    <Button id="b5" class="option option1">APPLIANCES</Button>
    <Button id="b6" class="option option2">COMPANION</Button>
    <Button id="b7" class="option option3">KIDS</Button>
    <Button id="b8" class="option option4">FOOD</Button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    $( ".option" ).on( "swipeleft", swipeHandler );
    $( ".option" ).on( "swiperight", swipeHandler )

    function swipeHandler( event ) {
        var current=$(this).parent().attr('id');
        console.log(current);
        //$( event.target ).addClass("hide");
        if(current=="div1") {
            $("div.app1").addClass("hide");
            $("div.app1").removeClass("show");
            $("div.app2").removeClass("hide");
            $("div.app2").addClass("show");
        }
        else {
            $("div.app2").addClass("hide");
            $("div.app2").removeClass("show");
            $("div.app1").addClass("show");
            $("div.app1").removeClass("hide");
        }
    }
```

Thanks